# PHP MySQL dropdown population with blank first option

Tags: php, html, mysql

**Edit: gbalduzzi solved it for me with what you guys call a "dirty fix" - which is now my favorite term in coding. Thank you all so much for the help!**

I'm very new to PHP/MySQL - and by new I mean the only experience I have is playing around with our site that was created by someone who didn't really care what his code looked like.

I'm attempting to fix a few issues our old IT guy had on our site. He was self-taught, so I'm sure this code I'm using is probably not up to current standards.
We have a contact list in our database, and that information is connected to this dropdown.

I'm trying to add a blank option so when you first load the page, there is no contact selected.
What I currently have adds a blank dropdown, but ends up selecting the blank option as the first contact, first option as the second contact, and so on.

Is there a way for me to implement the blank option without ruining the contact selection?

```
<select class="inputbox" id="job_contacts" name="job_contacts" onchange="Choice();">
    <?php
    echo '<option value=""></option>';
    foreach ($uArr as $key=>$value) {
        echo '<option value="'.$key.'">'.$value['contact_name'].'</option>'; 
    }
    ?>
</select>
```

Here is the array he created:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        var nam = new Array();
        var pho = new Array();
        var email = new Array();
        <?php
            foreach($uArr as $key=>$value) {
                echo "nam[" . $key . "] = '" . $value['contact_name'] . "';\n";
                echo "pho[" . $key . "] = '" . $value['contact_phone'] . "';\n";
                echo "email[" . $key . "] = '" . $value['contact_email'] . "';\n";
            }
            ?>

        function Choice() {
            x = document.getElementById("nam");
            y = document.getElementById("job_contacts");
            x.value = y.options[y.selectedIndex].text;
            document.getElementById("nam").value = nam[y.selectedIndex];
            document.getElementById("pho").value = pho[y.selectedIndex];
            document.getElementById("email").value = email[y.selectedIndex];
        }
    </script>
```

Comment: Can you reformulate "What I currently have adds a blank dropdown, but ends up selecting the blank option as the first contact, first option as the second contact, and so on." ? I use this blank option pattern a lot and never encountered an issue

Comment: @Pierre me too. It will be great if you could explain bit more

Comment: @RiggsFolly That didn't change anything, unfortunately.

Comment: @Marina are you expecting to have a blank option as the first selected option

Comment: A "dirty" fix would be like `... nam[" . $key + 1 . "] = ...` - But the next one, who reads that code will hate you.

Comment: So for example - let's say in the database, the first contact is Phil and the second is John. 
When I select the blank option, Phil's information shows up. 
When I select the second option, which is Phil's name, John's information shows up. So it's acting as if the blank option is the first contact when it populates the information. 

And by "shows up," I mean that on the webpage there are 3 input areas where the database information for their name, phone number, and email are populated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After adding the blank option, you need to  edit the Choice function accordingly:

```js
function Choice() {
            x = document.getElementById("nam");
            y = document.getElementById("job_contacts");
            var index = y.selectedIndex - 1;
            if (index < 0) return
            x.value = y.options[index].text;
            document.getElementById("nam").value = nam[index];
            document.getElementById("pho").value = pho[index];
            document.getElementById("email").value = email[index];
        }
```

Comment: Yeah it's a dirty fix, but it should do the trick. Happy to help!

Comment: Haha I can see that, but until I officially learn how to remake this whole site, I'll have to do some dirty fixes! Appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this:

change

```
echo '<option value=""></option>';
```

to

```
echo '<option selected value=""></option>';
```